# Which topics & books should I read to understand whirlpool, tornado, hurricane etc.?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, weather, meteorology

I want to be expert to understand physics behind whirlpool, tornado, hurricane. Which topics are needed for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a masters in meteorology so I think I can point you in the right direction.  First question though: how comfortable are you with math?  All of the things you listed involve an immense amount of math to fully understand.  Whirlpools are something you would study in fluid dynamics, tornadoes you would study in mesoscale meteorology and hurricanes in synoptic meteorology.  So first up:

1. Whirlpools: I'm not really sure what a good book is on fluid dynamics because the one I had to use was awful.  Amazon.com should turn up some decent results though.
2. Tornadoes: Markowski and Richardson have a **great** text on mesoscale meteorology.  The book is called "Mesoscale Meteorology in the Mid-Latitudes".  It has an excellent section in there on tornadoes and the physics behind them.
3. Hurricanes: As far as a good text for tropical meteorology, I'm not really sure.  When I was doing tropical meteorology in graduate school we didn't use a book, we read American Meteorological Society articles and relied on the notes we took from our professor.